# How to Find What a Particular Keyboard Shortcut Does?

Tags: keyboard

How can I find the command triggered by a keyboard shortcut without activating it in any given application?

When I press a keyboard shortcut, the top-level menu is highlighted, but, beyond that, I don't get much information about where the command is located, or what exactly it does. Sometimes I discover a key combination (by accident or guessing) that does more or less what I want but I can't find the details in documentation because I don't know the name of the command.

Comment: I've written [an AppleScript](http://superuser.com/a/415221/69039) that saves plain text lists of shortcuts in different applications, but running it usually takes a few seconds. In one of the worst offenders, TextMate, you can search for shortcut strings in the window opened by Bundles > TextMate > List Shortcuts (⌥⌘K).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that (and KeyCue; I probably won't fork over $20 for that, though). I don't have enough rep to upvote your comment. If there isn't a better solution you could just put that as an answer.

Incidentally I was wondering about this for Sublime Text 2, which actually has all the key bindings listed in JSON under Preferences > Key Bindings - {Default,User}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the name of every shortcut in an app by using a free app called [CheatSheet](http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/).